# Unable to open IIS on windows 10 after enabling Windows feature

Tags: windows, iis, configuration, iis-express

I have turned on IIS on Windows feature but I am unable to open IIS in my personal laptop. Can you please help to solve the issue?

[image]

But if I try to open **inetmgr**, it shows the below error.

[image]

One thing I observed that IIS is not there in in Windows Administrative Tool(screenshot below) so tried to install IIS from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264 but its is showing that latest version is already present in your computer.

Can you please help?

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/discover-installed-components Use registry keys to tell what exactly are the IIS components you installed on this machine first.

Answer (score 0):

To enable IIS and the required IIS components on Windows 10, do the following:

1)Open Control Panel and click Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off.

2)Enable Internet Information Services.

3)Expand the Internet Information Services feature and verify that the web server components listed in the next section are enabled.

4)Click OK.

Required IIS components:

-Web Management Tools

IIS 6 Management Compatibility

```
  IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility
```

IIS Management Console

IIS Management Scripts and Tools

IIS Management Service

-World Wide Web Services

Application Development Features

```
  .NET Extensibility 4.5

   ASP.NET 4.5

   ISAPI Extensions

   ISAPI Filters

   WebSocket Protocol
```

Common HTTP Features

```
   Default Document

   Static Content
```

Security

```
   Basic Authentication

   Request Filtering

   Windows Authentication
```

To ensure that IIS is installed and working, type IIS in the Search bar near the Start button. You’ll see the Internet Information Services Manager as a result. Click on that to open it.